# Gitlab CICD - Workflow in include overwriting all variables instead of just adding more

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a 1 repository that have a test-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build

workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
           SOME_VARIABLE: $SOME_PROD_VARIABLE
           SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_PROD_VARIABLE

workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "non-prod"
      variables:
           SOME_VARIABLE: $SOME_NP_VARIABLE
           SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_NP_VARIABLE

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $SOME_VARIABLE
    - echo $SECOND_VARIABLE
```

2 repository .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'firstrepo'
    file:
      - 'test-ci.yml'

variables:
  PORT: 5000

workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "non-prod"
      variables:
           SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_NP_VARIABLE

workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
           SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_PROD_VARIABLE
```

i want the second project's workflow to overwrite/add the variables, but it replaces all the variables so $SOME_VARIABLE is None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the configuration merging mechanism in Gitlab CI/CD (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#merge-method-for-include) workflow rules from the main file (here *.gitlab-ci.yml*) override the rules from included file:

> When the key exists in both A and B, and one of the values is not a hash map, use the value from B.

Here the key is *workflow.rules* and it is a sequence that exists in both files.
In *test-ci.yml* you effectively have:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
        SOME_VARIABLE: $SOME_PROD_VARIABLE
        SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_PROD_VARIABLE
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "non-prod"
      variables:
        SOME_VARIABLE: $SOME_NP_VARIABLE
        SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_NP_VARIABLE
```

And in *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "non-prod"
      variables:
        SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_NP_VARIABLE
    - if $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
        SECOND_VARIABLE: $SECOND_PROD_VARIABLE
```

Upon merging the second definition of *rules* overrides the first one so *SOME_VARIABLE* is missing.

I see two possible solutions here:

1. In case both workflows are actually identical and the only difference is the value assigned to *SOME_VARIABLE* then remove workflow definition from *.gitlab-ci.yml* and instead define *SOME_PROD_VARIABLE* and *SOME_NP_VARIABLE* variables there.
2. In case when you need to modify the workflow rules then you must copy the workflow from *test-ci.yml* and modify accordingly.